# How to store calculation inside a for loop, so every time it is calculated, a integer value is updated and later printed out, C

Tags: c, for-loop, cs50

Details of my goal : Say we have a population of n llamas. Each year, n / 3 new llamas are born, and n / 4 llamas pass away.

For example, if we were to start with n = 1200 llamas, then in the first year, 1200 / 3 = 400 new llamas would be born and 1200 / 4 = 300 llamas would pass away. At the end of that year, we would have 1200 + 400 - 300 = 1300 llamas.

I have come to a conclusion that, every 1200 / 3 and 1200 / 4 one year passes and now I am trying to use a for loop to iterate a variable that every time the calculation is done, it iterates + 1 meaning it counts as one year has passed, and then later prints out the amount of years that passed.

Expected results: 
./population 
**Start size: 100

End size: 1000000

Years: 115**

This is what I have tried so far. I believe everything is right in this code except the for loop, I cannot get the logic of how a calculation should be done and then later printed out. I always end up with a zero for year.

Here is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int start_pop_size;
    int end_pop_size;
    int years_passed;


    // TODO: Prompt for start size

        do
        {
          start_pop_size = get_int ("Enter starting population size: \n");
        }
        while (start_pop_size < 9);

    // TODO: Prompt for end size
        do
        {
            end_pop_size = get_int ("Enter ending population size: \n");
        }
        while (end_pop_size <= start_pop_size);

    // TODO: Calculate number of years
    for(years_passed = 0; years_passed < start_pop_size / 3 - end_pop_size / 4; years_passed++)
    {
        int calculation = start_pop_size / 3 - end_pop_size / 4;
    }

     // TODO: Print number of years

    printf("Years : %i", years_passed);
}
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Although the idea of `0.333333333333` of a baby llama, or a llama that is 25% dead is kind of horrifying...

Comment: Hint: with `start_pop_size = 100` and  `end_pop_size = 1000000`, what is `start_pop_size / 3 - end_pop_size / 4` ? What will happen with the for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. uses `size_t` for years as that value will never be < 0
4. separated input values from calculated values
5. notice this algorithm fails when the starting population is 3 or less

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int start_pop_size;
    int end_pop_size;
    

    do
    {
        start_pop_size = get_int ("Enter starting population size: \n");
    }
    while (start_pop_size < 9);


    do
    {
        end_pop_size = get_int ("Enter ending population size: \n");
    }
    while (end_pop_size <= start_pop_size);


    
    size_t years_passed = 0;
    int new_pop = start_pop_size;
    for( int old_pop = start_pop_size; 
         new_pop < end_pop_size; 
         years_passed++ )
    {
        printf( "\nloopStart: oldPop:%d /3:%d /4:%d\n", old_pop, old_pop/3, old_pop/4 );
        new_pop +=  old_pop/3 - old_pop/4;
        old_pop = new_pop;
        printf( "loopEnd: newPop:%d\n", new_pop );
    }

    printf("Years : %zu", years_passed);
}
```

a run with the OPs proposed input values:

```
Enter starting population size: 
100
Enter ending population size: 
1000000
Years : 115
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't know beforehand how many iterations it'll take to reach the `end_pop_size`, so your condition can't be based on `years_passed`. Instead you need to keep track of the current population and decide when to end your loop based on that:

```
int cur_pop_size = start_pop_size;
years_passed = 0;
do {
    // calculation goes here
    years_passed++;
while (cur_pop_size < end_pop_size);
```

You could also express this as a `for`, but again note that the condition is about the `cur_pop_size` rather than about the `years_passed`:

```
int cur_pop_size = start_pop_size;
for (years_passed = 0; cur_pop_size < end_pop_size; years_passed++) {
    // calculation goes here
}
```

Comment: Well you can, but a do - while is certainly more suitable

Comment: @klutt sure, added that alternative. I prefer the `while` formulation since the end condition isn't based on the loop variable.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that you solution is much better. The for version is not even worth mentioning. I just objected to the claim that it *cannot* be used. :)

Comment: First I updated my code as following: 
// TODO: Calculate number of years

    int cur_pop_size = start_pop_size;
    years_passed = 0;

    do {
start_pop_size / 3 - end_pop_size / 4;

    years_passed++;
    }
while (cur_pop_size < end_pop_size);

     // TODO: Print number of years

    printf("Years : %i", years_passed);
After which I'd get an error saying that I need to store the result into something.
So I did, I stored it as such:

years_passed = start_pop_size / 3 - end_pop_size / 4;
after run and entering populations, i would not get result and program wouldn't end

Comment: @Nermin You need to update the `cur_pop_size` in every iteration based on your formula, not `years_passed`.

Comment: So in my do...while loop I should type, cur_pop_size++ instead of years_passed?

Comment: @Nermin -- no, `years_passed++` is incrementing the year every loop, that needs to stay. `cur_pop_size` needs to be updated to the new population based on your "calculation" formula: `cur_pop_size += (cur_pop_size/3) - (cur_pop_size/4);`

Comment: I got it! Sorry for confusion from my part. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int start_size (void);
int end_size (int x);

int main(void)
{
    int start = start_size();
    int end = end_size(start);

    // size_t is uesed as a integer type that is never be less than 0 
    // (positive number) 
    //And It needs "%zu" to print out
    size_t years = 0;

    int new_start = start;

    for(int old = start ;
        new_start < end ;
        years++)
    {

        new_start += old / 3 - old / 4;
        old = new_start;
    }

    printf("Years: %zu\n",years);
}

int start_size (void)
{
    int s;
    do
    {
        s = get_int("Start Size: ");
    }
    while(s < 9);
    return s;
}

int end_size (int x)// x  is the starting point
{
    int e;
    do
    {
        e = get_int("End Size: ");
    }
    while(e <= x);
    return e;
}
```